# Using Vulkan with SFML?

Tags: c++, sfml, vulkan

Im currently using GLFW for window creation and user input. GLFW simply allows us to say:

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);

To tell GLFW were not working with OpenGL. It even provides function like

```
glfwCreateWindowSurface(...)
```

To automate window surface creation for different platforms.

Is there any way I can do something similar with SFML? I could not find any information about it on their website, so i assume the answer is no. But maybe there is some kind of hack, or is this not advised?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vulkan is supported in the next minor release; [SFML 2.6.0](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/projects/4).

The new [`sf::WindowBase`](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/include/SFML/Window/WindowBase.hpp) class, serves as the base class for all Windows. It  provides a simple interface for manipulating the window: move, resize, show/hide, control mouse cursor, etc. It also provides event handling through its pollEvent() and waitEvent() functions.

[`sf::Window`](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/include/SFML/Window/Window.hpp) still serves as a target for OpenGL rendering, but it now inherits the above functionality from sf::WindowBase. This design choice was done, so as to not break existing code: [see the full discussion for info](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/pull/1484).

The new `sf::WindowBase` does not create an OpenGL context by default. Instead it provides a public member function [`createVulkanSurface`](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/include/SFML/Window/WindowBase.hpp) with the following definition.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// \brief Create a Vulkan rendering surface
///
/// \param instance  Vulkan instance
/// \param surface   Created surface
/// \param allocator Allocator to use
///
/// \return True if surface creation was successful, false otherwise
///
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
bool createVulkanSurface(const VkInstance& instance, VkSurfaceKHR& surface, const VkAllocationCallbacks* allocator = 0);
```

A demonstration of usage (some 2.600 lines of code), can be found under [examples in the SFML respiratory](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/tree/master/examples/vulkan).

Comment: With 2.6.0, will it be possible to create a RenderWindow that renders to a Vulkan surface?

Answer (score 4):

This is not yet integrated into SFML, but [there's an open pull request adding/discussing this feature](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/pull/1484).