# Getting HWND and HInstance of SFML window?

Tags: c++, winapi, sfml

I've been unable to find anything about this. Given a window created with SFML (assuming ofcourse were on Windows):

```
sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "My window");
```

Is it possible to get the actual HWND and HInstance of the created window? Some getter? or perhaps a neat hack?

Something like:

```
window.getHWND()
window.getHInstance()
```

Would be pretty ideal, but it dosent exist. Any suggestions are appreciated.

**Update**

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52963428/using-vulkan-with-sfml), because im specifically asking how to retrive the HWND and HInstance of the SFML window. Not how to integrate Vulkan with SFML. So issues of an SFML window already having a swapchain is irrelevant to this question, not to the other one tho. I just included the context in case anyone was wondering. *Sorry for the confusion*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is `sf::Window::getSystemHandle()`, which will return a `sf::WindowHandle`, which is platform dependent and on Windows it's basically the `HWND`.

To get your `HINSTANCE`, either use your own `WinMain()` entry point or call `GetModuleHandle(NULL);` as long as you're not writing a library.

Comment: That's only half an answer. It doesn't explain how to retrieve the module handle identifying the module that registered the respective window class. Apparently, that's part of the information the OP needs.

Comment: Yes, I was to quick to accept an answer there. I assumed this would also retrive the module handle. I do need that.

Comment: Isn't it unusable? It is basically invalid to create Vulkan swapchain on window that already has swapchain. See Issue 2 in `VK_KHR_win32_surface` spec.

Comment: Added. @krOoze I have no idea and only focused on the the core question: retrieving the identifiers. Whether the original goal is achievable is a different question, but the OP has a second question regarding the context/swap chain.

Answer (score 0):

This is practically a duplicate of [Using Vulkan with SFML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52963428/using-vulkan-with-sfml), but asked as a XY problem.

OpenGL seems to be hard dependency of SFML. I **assume** SFML immediatelly calls `SetPixelFormat`, and creates OpenGL swap chain (i.e. "context") on top of it.

If that is so, that makes it unusable in Vulkan. If it works, that would be only because undefined behavior, or because non-compliant Vulkan Implementation.

It is discussed in two places in the Vulkan Specification.

Firstly Issue 2) in `VK_KHR_win32_surface` appendix goes over it thoroughly. In summary it says:

> Uses of a window object by multiple graphics APIs results in undefined behavior.

Secondly in `vkCreateSwapchainKHR` behavior it says:

> If the native window referred to by `surface` is already associated with a non-Vulkan graphics API surface, `VK_ERROR_NATIVE_WINDOW_IN_USE_KHR` **must** be returned.

Comment: Ive updated the question, and removed the Vulkan context.